# Unity Shader Graph - Custom Function ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

Didn't find a solution after a bit of searching so I thought about asking here...

Inside Shader Graph, deleting a Custom Function causes a Index out of range: -1.
When this happens, I'm unable to save the shader.

The exception is thrown in com.unity.shadergraph@14.0.6/Editor/Drawing/Views/MaterialGraphEditWindow.cs:384

I'm using Unity v2022.2.9

Has anyone experienced this?

I've added a custom function, specified the type "File" and added a source shader file.
Later on, I've tried deleting said custom function and the error above presented itself.
I've tried removing the source file by setting the field to "none" but that didn't change the result.